# SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CATEGORYID": invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER1
  (
   CUSTOMERID          VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
   FIRSTNAME           VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   LASTNAME            VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   PHONENUMBER         VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   BIRTHDATE           DATE NOT NULL,
   DRIVERLICENSENUMBER NUMBER,
   STATUS              VARCHAR2(50),
   CREDITCARENUMBER    NUMBER,
   CONSTRAINT CustomerID_PK PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMERID)
  );



CREATE TABLE CCATEGORY
 (
  CATEGORYID   INT NOT NULL,
  CATEGORYNAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT categoryID_pk PRIMARY KEY (CATEGORYID)
);


CREATE TABLE TAPE
 (
TAPEID         NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
TAPETITLE      VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
RELEASEYEAR    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
DATEPURCHASED  DATE NOT NULL,
PRICE          NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,
RENTEDOUT      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
RATING         VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ACTIONONRETURN VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(TAPEID),
CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORYID FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORYID) REFERENCES CCATEGORY(CATEGORYID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESERVEDBY FOREIGN KEY(CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID)
);
```

Customer, and CCategory table are created. When I try to create TAPE table I get the following error: `SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CATEGORYID": invalid identifier`. Can't seem to figure out why. I created the customer table first, then the category table before trying to create the TAPE table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have not defined `CATEGORYID` and `CUSTOMERID` in `TAPE` table. Add it and it would work.

Complete statement would be

```
CREATE TABLE TAPE
 (
TAPEID         NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
TAPETITLE      VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
RELEASEYEAR    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
DATEPURCHASED  DATE NOT NULL,
PRICE          NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,
RENTEDOUT      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
RATING         VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ACTIONONRETURN VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
CATEGORYID   INT NOT NULL,
CUSTOMERID          VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tape_primary_key PRIMARY KEY(TAPEID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORYID FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORYID) REFERENCES CCATEGORY(CATEGORYID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESERVEDBY FOREIGN KEY(CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER1(CUSTOMERID)
);
```

Comment: Check the updated answer. Problem is that you have not defied `CATEGORYID` and `CUSTOMERID` in `TAPE` table. Add it and it will work.